# I can't get stdClass Object value in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cant get object value in codeigniter.
The code message like that : Message: Trying to get property 'img' of non-object

```
        foreach ($getAllProductsQuality as $productsQuality) {
    $getMainImage = $t->products_model->getImage(array('sku', 'img', 'file', 'folder', 'title'), array('status' => 1, 'main' => 1, 'sku' => $productsQuality->sku));
    $getDataImages = $t->products_model->getImage(array('sku', 'position','img'), array('status' => 1,'position' => 2, 'sku' => $productsQuality->sku));
    print_r($getDataImages->img);//problem is here
    $productsImg = base_url() . 'assets/img/preparing-image.jpg';
    $productsImgTitle = 'Preparing Image';
    if (!empty($getMainImage->img)) {
        $productsImg = image(adminURL . $getMainImage->img, 268, 357);
        $productsImgTitle = $getMainImage->title;
    }
```

and i try print_r for value:

```
print_r($getDataImages->img);
```

my query output like that:

```
          stdClass Object
(
    [sku] => 37205
    [position] => 2
    [img] => uploads/product/Almeras/almeras-23634-110-top.png
)
stdClass Object
(
    [sku] => 37326
    [position] => 2
    [img] => uploads/product/Almeras/almeras-23642-956-top.png
)
```

what i do wrong ?

Comment: Looks like your query does not return a stdClass object, but an array of objects. That array does not have any `img` property, the individual stdClass objects contained in it do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your query

```
$t->products_model->getImage(array('sku', 'position','img'), array('status' => 1,'position' => 2, 'sku' => $productsQuality->sku));
```

is returning nothing, so there probably is no image. You can test this by using `var_dump($getDataImages)`.

**Regarding your edit:**
I think the first two items in `$getAllProductsQuality` do have an image associated (37205 and 37326) but there is probably another `$getAllProductsQuality` without an image associated. How many items are in this `$getAllProductsQuality` array? Can you put `var_dump($getDataImages)` in front of the print_r?

Comment: i add query's output in top

Comment: @AlperUluses I've edited my answer accordingly